# Discord detect activity change spotify

Tags: python, discord

Here I am again, I am creating a feature that detects the song you're listening to, but I'm having trouble getting it to work. Code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_update(before, after):
  print('working 1')
  if isinstance(activity, Spotify):
    print('working 2')
    embed = discord.Embed(title = f"{after.name}'s Spotify", description = "Listening to '{}'".format(activity.title), color = 0xC902FF)
    embed.set_thumbnail(url=activity.album_cover_url)
    embed.add_field(name="Artist", value=activity.artist)
    embed.add_field(name="Album", value=activity.album)
    embed.set_footer(text="Song started at {}".format(activity.created_at.strftime("%H:%M")))
    channel = bot.get_channel(844103211266998272)
    await channel.send(embed=embed)
    print(activity.title)
    print(activity.artist)
```

It prints 'working 1' but it does not get past 'if isinstance(activity, Spotify):' (so it doesnt print 'working 2')
Help pls someone?

Comment: and i did: from discord import Spotify

Comment: Hi, you might want to create a [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easier to debug the code, and explain your problem a bit more. Saying it doesn't work isn't much. Why do you expect the instance check to work?

Answer (score 0):

Where does the variable `activity` come from? Maybe you'd want to use `after.activity`

Comment: but i know that the code does not get past the isinstance line, so do you know anything 'bout that?